# Keycloak ignores realmRoles when adding a user by rest api

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

When I am creating a new user by using Keycloak rest API, the application ignores the realmRoles property not assigning the role to the new user.
Here is an exemple

```
POST: https://localhost:8543/auth/admin/realms/quarkus/users

Body:
{
   "username":"alexandre",
   "enabled":true,
   "emailVerified":true,
   "firstName":"Alexandre",
   "lastName":"Oliveira",
   "email":"alexandreqogmailcom",
   "credentials":[
      {
         "type":"password",
         "value":"123456",
         "temporary":false
      }
   ],
   "realmRoles":[
      "user_esc"
   ],
   "access":{
      "mapRoles":true
   }
```

Is there a way to resolve this problem or a work around ?

**PS:** I am using the keycloak version 12.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are expecting that with the endpoint:

```
POST: https://localhost:8543/auth/admin/realms/quarkus/users
```

it will also create the realm roles, that will not happen, it will not create the Realm roles. To create the Realm roles you either use the Admin Console or you use the endpoint:

```
POST https://localhost:8543/auth/admin/realms/quarkus/roles
```

with the payload

`{"name":"<ROLE_NAME>","description":"<DESCRIPTION>"}`

if it is a non Composite Realm Role.

To assign the Realm Role to the user, after having create the user, call the endpoint:

```
POST: https://localhost:8543/auth/admin/realms/quarkus/users/<USER_ID>/role-mappings/realm
```

with the payload

```
[{"id":"<Role ID>","name":"<Role Name>"}]
```

The role ID you can get it from:

```
GET: https://localhost:8543/auth/admin/realms/quarkus/roles/<ROLE_NAME>
```

and the user ID from :

```
GET: https://localhost:8543/auth/admin/realms/quarkus/users/?username=<USERNAME>
```

I have upload the [following bash scripts](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/blob/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI/Roles/assignRealmRoleToUser.sh) to automatize this process.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@dreamcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65405204/1366871) answer I was able to make a python function for this. I'm sharing in case someone else needs it.

It requires the following dependency: [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

```py
BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8081"
REALM_ID = "toto"
REALM_NAME = "toto"

def get_token() -> str:
    resp = requests.post(
        url=f"{BASE_URL}/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token",
        data={
            "client_id": "admin-cli",
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "admin",
            "grant_type": "password",
        },
    )
    access_token = resp.json()["access_token"]
    logging.info(f"access_token: {access_token}")
    return access_token

def create_user(session: Session, email: str, role_name: str | None = None):
    # Create user
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/admin/realms/{REALM_ID}/users/"
    request_body = {
        "email": email,
        "username": email,
        "emailVerified": True,
        "enabled": True,
    }
    data = json.dumps(request_body)
    resp = session.post(url, data=data)

    # get user id
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/admin/realms/{REALM_ID}/users/?username={email}"
    resp = session.get(url)
    user_id = resp.json()[0]["id"]

    # get role id
    # GET: https://localhost:8543/auth/admin/realms/quarkus/roles/<ROLE_NAME>
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/admin/realms/{REALM_ID}/roles/{role_name}"
    resp = session.get(url)
    role_id = resp.json()["id"]

    # create role-mapping
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/admin/realms/{REALM_ID}/users/{user_id}/role-mappings/realm"
    request_body = [{"id":role_id,"name":role_name}] 
    data = json.dumps(request_body)
    resp = session.post(url, data=data)

ACCESS_TOKEN = get_token()
session = Session()
session.headers.update({"Content-Type": "application/json"})
session.headers.update({"Authorization": f"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}"})

create_user(
        session=session,
        email="admin@toto.fr",
        role_name="toto-admin",
    )
```